# Why can't I stop on frame 1 of Flash timeline?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I try to create a tab interface:
[image]

So on each layer in frame 1 I added

```
this.stop();
```

but when running it says:

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript.
```

main.as is currently useless but I can show it in case it would have impact:

```
package {   
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.controls.CheckBox;

    public class main extends Sprite {      

      public function main() {  
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );     
      }

      public function init( e:Event ):void {
        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
      }         

      public function hello(target:MouseEvent) {
        trace(target);  
      } 
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use FrameScripting and don't use it when you have a document class. Use the Event.ENTER_FRAME to determine where your playhead is. Than you can use FrameLabels to make it flexible to manage.
But in the Code above, you are extending Sprite, so there is no play()- and stop()-method which your frames could execute. Also the addFrameScript() method is not available, so try to extend MovieClip, that should work.

Greetings
philipp

Comment: your explanation is a bit confusing.

Comment: I concur with Phillip that mixing frame scripts with playback-head-controlling code from the document class is a bad idea. If you do it, you have to be very conscious of what order scripts get executed in and manage potential conflicts. If you aren't careful about this, I can guaranty you that you'll have bugs where the playback head didn't move when you thought it would, or went to the wrong frame.

Comment: I'm learning Flash that's why I do it that way but next step I'll try your advice thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since your document class extends Sprite, it doesn't have the stop method. A Sprite doesn't have a timeline or frames. If you want to use a document class and have multiple frames on the main timeline, you should instead extend MovieClip.

So you could change this:

```
public class main extends Sprite {
```

... to this:

```
public class main extends MovieClip {
```

Comment: agree with Lars on this one.  Link for more info: http://www.ericd.net/2008/11/1180-call-to-possibly-undefined-method.html

Comment: Agreed. This is the most direct, correct answer for the question.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been already told, you need to extend MovieClip to have a timeline. 
Also

> So on each layer in frame 1 I added
>
> ```
> this.stop();
> ```
>
> You don't need to add a stop on each layer. If the action is defined in one frame, it will affect all layers on that frame.